# Piping inside a pipe voids tapping in the outer one in RXJS during a get call in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I noticed that some of my `tap(...)` invokations won't log to console, so I investigated further and found that an inner piping seems to kill off the outer piping. For instance, the code below, will show *inner* but won't show *outer*.

```
return this.http.get<{ token: string }>(url)
  .pipe(

    tap(_ => console.log("outer")),

    switchMap(_ => {
      ...
      return of(id);
    }),

    catchError(_ => {

      const urlLocal = url.replace(domainProd, domainDev);
      return this.http.get<{ token: string }>(urlLocal)
        .pipe(

          tap(_ => console.log("inner")),

          switchMap(_ => {
            ...
            return of(id);
          })

        );
    })
  );
```

I'm not sure I understand how to explain it nor how to infer this behavoir from [the docs for `tap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do). As far I figure, the tapping is piped to occur prior to the call invokation and, hence, prior to any error being detected.

Apparently, I'm mistaken somehow but I'd like to see it documented or explained somehow and, obviously I failed to find that information too.

As for the structure, if it's surprising, we have an environment on the server that works with the outer and, if run locally, fails, switching to the inner one. Finally, I'm getting a token from which I'm getting `sub` only, switching the map to the simple string and returning it as an observable.

Comment: The tap operator takes up to 3 callbacks. The first is only called in case a (success) value is emitted, but not when the observable goes in errror.

Try this

tap(
 result => console.log("outer next", result),
 err => console.log("outer error", err),
)

Comment: In case you would be using RXJS version 6, I personally find this site a much better resource:   https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap

Comment: Or this: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap

Comment: @mcoomans That should be posted as a reply to be accepted as correct answer. I have two follow-ups to it and I'd prefer to post them to an answer. Can you repost as such, please? And feel free to inject the link by DeborahK, preferably with a short mention on the difference between them as well as why the one I've been using is not to be preferred in RXJS 6 (which is the one I'm using as I installed a new distribution of Angular).

Comment: @DeborahK Would you be able to mention a few words on why the resource you've suggested (and the one that mcoomans did too) are better suited than the one I linked to, as well as which of your suggestion is to be preferred when?

Comment: The `rxjs.dev` site is the official site for the RxJS library and is maintained by the same team that maintains RxJS. (My link is newer, the firebaseapp link was the older reference) You can see that this documentation is included in the RxJS github repo here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/docs_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tap operator takes up to 3 callbacks. The first one is called in case a (success) value is emitted, but not when the observable goes in error. Try this as your first tap operator:

```
 tap( 
   result => console.log("outer next", result), 
   err => console.log("outer error", err), 
 )
```

In case your first http call fails, you should see a log of "outer error" before any code inside your `catchError` operator is called.

Assuming your are learning the latest RXJS 6, I would recommend using  [rxjs.dev](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) as your first source of reference. (Thanks to @DeborahK for that link).
The site that you referred to [www.learnrxjs.io](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) has a nice primer, but once you get the basic concepts I find its documentation of operators too limited. The official rxjs.dev site  documents their full interface, describes their behaviour also for edge cases, and typically provides a similar number of code samples.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that placing `tap(...)` first of all doens't really matter, does it? It's going to react to successful/failed invocation to the API. Am I correct there or still confusing things? I'm thinking that the reactive observation of the call's outcome is independent of switch-mapping it to the next stage of data format. Can you confirm/refute that statement, please?

Comment: The presence of that first `tap(...)` doesn't effect the observations in the `switchMap` operator, because a `tab(..)` leaves the observable sequence of pushed values unchanged.  Your switchMap on the other hand does impact the observable. Before the SwitchMap, you an Observable<{token:string}> ; after the switch you get an Observable<string> . If you would insert another tab(..) with console.logs after that switchMap, you would see different values logged in that second tab() compared to the first tab().